# Show currency switcher in custom template file Magento2

Tags: magento2, template, currency

I am trying to show currency switcher in custom template file.

I referred some links and found for magento1.

Where they used below code in the template files.

```
  <?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Same code i tried in magento2, which is not working.

I have tried this also in my template file.

```
 <?php echo  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Which is not working.

Can anyone help me is there any other way to achieve this functionality.

Thanks!!

Comment: Good to hear that you have resolved your issue. +1 for anwer acceptance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock("Magento\Directory\Block\Currency")
            ->setTemplate("Magento_Directory::currency.phtml")
            ->toHtml();
```

This should work anywhere in any phtml

Comment: This worked for me.. Thanks

Comment: it's working for me